# skimage.morphology does not contain Mediall_axis (python/ image process)

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image, straight-line-detection

Dears,

my scikit, skimage does not contain medial_axis
Hence I get this below error while running

(python/ image process)

"medial_axis" is not defined

i tried uninstall and install skimage-image using pip install
but it did not work out

[update]

I had a file named "skimage.py" that was the reason it did not work anyway

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your [mcve] and complete error message. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Feel free to delete the post.